# In QGIS is there a way to select one feature from a layer and only see related features from another layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I am self taught.

I have 3 layers on my map: Retailer, Producer and Processor.  Each business in each of these categories has a unique identifier, their license number.

I have a CSV file with a list of all sales between Processor and retailer.  The problem is that for every transaction there is a new line in the CSV file.
So if A processor sold to 15 retailers then each sale relationship has a line (including the unique license number for the processor) so when I relate this table only to the processor layer it only adds the first sale.  I want to be able to show all retailers that the particular processor sold too.

[image: processor to retail sales]

The next request is is there a way to, once the above is completed, to select a processor on the map and have all of the retailers sold to show up and no other retailers?

Answer (score 1):

First request: It sounds like you are using the 'Join' function in the layer properties. You actually need to go into Project>Project Properties>Relations to view 1:n relationships.
This enables you to select a feature and in the form that pops up you will have a sub table with all the retailers. Joins only work 1:1.

Second request: You may need to create a custom function to query the relation and return a value if >0 records are returned. Then you can use this function in a rule based symbology.

Alternatively put the dataset and the CSV file in an SpatiaLite database and create a view that has true/false for if a record from one table has a record from another. Then join this view to the table and symbolise on the joined field.